# How to make a creature pretty?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am well aware that the beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but listen to me if you will. We are currently playing D&D 5e, a nautical adventure. I asked the DM if I could have a mermaid fall in love with my character and have her as a wife later, except what fell in love with my character was not a mermaid but rather a Kuo-toa. Now we are stuck with this walking smelly fish and, as a roleplayer, I really wanted her to be more human.

Is there any way to turn a creature into a beautiful human, permanently? Or at least some sort of humanoid(that does not have a fish head).

Comment: Considering that the DM enabled this situation in the first place, have you asked the DM for options?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This feels like the prelude to a r/relationships post somehow.

Comment: Generally the go-to for artists trying to make their creations cute is to make its eyes really big compared to the rest of its body. Perhaps this is where we get the expression "Beauty is in the eye of the Beholder"?

Comment: @T.E.D. I always just figured that one of those eyestalks had a CHA-enhancing ray, but it never uses that one, so the beauty remains inside...

Comment: You asked for a mermaid and got a kuo-toa... I like your DM already!

Comment: Fresh fish don't smell. Did your DM send you an *undead* kuo-toa? ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Circlet of human perfection

It's an uncommon magic item, described in the *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* (p. 30).

The description of the [*circlet of human perfection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/circlet-of-human-perfection) says:

> This circlet is an uncommon magic item called a *circlet of human perfection*. Only humanoids can attune to it. The circlet transforms its attuned wearer into an attractive human of average height

Another way is high-level magic like Wish or True Polymorph.

Comment: And Kuo-toa's response after: "I'm so ugly!"

Comment: @NautArch might be, but the OP asked for a "way to turn a creature into a beautiful *human*" explicitly

Comment: Variant: "circelet of human medriocreness": The circelet transforms its attuned wearer into an all around average human (of the approriate gender, whatever)

Answer (score 12):

### Reincarnate, True Polymorph, or Wish spells are options.

If you don't mind the morally grey action of having your fish-wife experience death so you can make her more attractive, the Druid spell *[Reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate)* lets you bring a humanoid back from the dead in a new form.  [Kuo-Toa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kuo-toa) (MM, p. 199) are technically humanoids, so this is one option.  And since Kuo-Toa are not an option on the Reincarnation table, you don't have to worry about her reincarnating into a Kuo-Toa again.

If you have more power to throw around, *[True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* allows you to transform a creature into another creature permanently (or at least until dispelled).  This 9th level spell can be accessed by Wizards, Bards, and Warlocks.

And of course, there's always *[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)*.  You could use it to reproduce the effects of *Reincarnate*, or you could just wish your fish-wife into a new form.  The latter would cause you to suffer the stress of producing an effect other than reproducing another spell and give you a chance to never be able to cast *Wish* again, though.  Wish is available to Sorcerers, Wizards, and Bards (only through Magical Secrets, though), as well as through magic items like a Ring of 3 Wishes or a Luck Blade.

Answer (score 5):

## Use "Mask of Many Faces"

Your sweetheart, aware that she is hideous to your sight, acquires a mask of many faces in order to magically disguise herself. Then she claims that this is a natural transformation that her kind is capable of, this fools you but it's totally bogus. She has to use this mask's ability every hour otherwise the spell will wear off. This adds a big role playing element to what she's doing while making you (and others) think she is very beautiful.

Comment: Are you referring to the warlock's Eldritch Invocation named "Mask of Many Faces", or describing a real magic item, or a homebrew magic item you've come up with yourself?